# Scala Spark - Reduce RDD by adding multiple values per key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark RDD that is in the format of (String, (Int, Int)) and I would like to add the Int values together to create a (String, Int) map.

This is an example of an element in my RDD:
res13: (String, (Int, Int)) = (9D4669B432A0FD,(1,1))

I would like to end with an RDD of (String, Int) = (9D4669B432A0FD,2)

Answer (score 5):

You should just `map` the values to the sum of the second pair:

```
yourRdd.map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2._1 + pair._2._2))
```

@marios suggested the following nicer syntax in an edit:

> Or if you want to make it a bit more readable:

```
yourRdd.map{case(str, (x1,x2)) => (str, x1+x2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gabor Bakos answer is correct if there are unique keys. But If you have multiple identical keys and if you want to reduce it to unique keys then use reduceByKey.

Example:

```
val data = Array(("9888wq",(1,2)),("abcd",(1,1)),("abcd",(3,2)),("9888wq",(4,2)))
val rdd= sc.parallelize(data)
val result = rdd.map(x => (x._1,(x._2._1+x._2._2))).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
result.foreach(println)
```

Output :

```
 (9888wq,9)
 (abcd,7)
```